# Safe way to upload large files with Angular?

Tags: angular

I am looking for a way to upload files directly on a server via Angular.
It is important that the method work with large files (+500 Mo) and that it be safe.

I thought about using SFTP in order to achieve this but it seems SSH & SFTP modules only work on a Node.js server.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not an Angular problem.  Angular is merely a client-side front-end library that encapsulates client-side front-end operations.  Therefore it is limited to what JavaScript can normally do, in your case, the HTTP/S and WS/S protocols.  You need to focus on creating a back-end that can receive files.